# How to achieve order fulfillment in drupal commerce like ubercart?

Tags: commerce

I'm new to drupal commerce. I would like to know how to achieve Order fulfillment in drupal commerce like ubercart. I'm using UPS,FedEx & USPS for shipping. I had seen package options in each shipping methods configuration. I'm confused to handle shipment process for orders. Is there shipment requirements has send automatically to respective shipping service(UPS,FedEx & USPS) after creating an order?

Please help me to get clear about handle order shipment process in drupal commerce.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried https://drupal.org/project/commerce_delivery at all? That appears to be used in conjunction with https://drupal.org/project/commerce_physical_fields and its dependent Physical Fields module.

Comment: Thanks "Ryan Szrama". I have tried it.But it seems to help to tracking deliveries of orders. My question is, how drupal commerce handling shipments for the customer  orders? & How are they handle UPS,FedEx & USPS? 


Can you please clarify my questions?

Comment: I'm sorry then, I'm not sure what you mean. Label creation?

Comment: In ubercart, there is a option to packaging and shipment for the order.How to achieve this in drupal commerce? Is there any way to packaging and shipment the order in drupal commerce? Like Commerce Postmaster does. https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/kafmil/2088841

Comment: I'd look into https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipment.

Comment: Oh! Ok great!. How about Label creation?